# ¿Cuál es el origen de "de tripas corazón"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, locuciones

(Hacer de) "tripas corazón" es un modismo conocido que salió en los títulos de canciones de los notados grupos Aterciopelados y Bersuit Vergarabat. Hacer algo de tripas corazón es hacer algo a pesar de ello ser desagradable. Pero ¿qué tiene eso que ver con tripas y corazones?

Pensé en principio que tal tarea se tendría que enfrentar con tripas y corazón, pero hallé otras teorías: ["Es transformar al corazón en una tripa, pues se supone que las tripas no encarnan a los sentimientos"](https://ar.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090908185651AA2Fg6H) y ["Al que le falta corazón para estar tranquilo, hágalo de las tripas"](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vcodigo=43640). Ya que esas fuentes no están de acuerdo, ¿hay más datos que nos explicarían como pasó a señalarse así, y lo que es su origen verdadero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hacer de tripas corazón*, si se interpreta literalmente, significa "transformar las tripas en corazón" o "usar tripas en sustitución del corazón". Esta forma de emplear el verbo *hacer* no es tan común actualmente. Hay canciones (ya que hablamos de canciones) con letras como *Hiciste de mí lo que yo soy* o *Has hecho de mi amor lo que has querido*, donde se usa con este significado; también existe un dicho, *Hizo de su capa un sayo*, que significa "hizo lo que quiso, según su libre albedrío" (una capa y un sayo son dos prendas de ropa).

En cuanto al origen de la frase *hacer de tripas corazón*, aparece documentada ya en el siglo XVI, aparentemente con el significado de "sacar fuerzas de donde no hay para hacer algo". No sólo se trata de que sea desagradable o indeseable, sino de que la persona no tiene ya "corazón" suficiente para hacerlo, es decir: no tiene ánimo, espíritu o coraje. Sólo le quedan "tripas", que son vísceras, un órgano que no es noble como el corazón.

En el Diccionario de Autoridades aparece un dicho relacionado que revela la relación:

> **[TRIPAS LLEVAN CORAZÓN, QUE NO CORAZÓN TRIPAS](http://web.frl.es/dtSearch/dtisapi6.dll?cmd=getdoc&DocId=53224&Index=C%3A%5Cinetpub%5Cwwwroot%5CDA_INDEX&HitCount=1&hits=1%20&SearchForm=%2FDA_form%2Ehtml)**. Refr. que enseña la mutua subordinacion, y dependencia, que tienen unas cosas con otras, y que no se deben desatender, las que por algun respeto se consideran de menor aprecio.

El refrán dice que las tripas llevan (sustentan, sostienen, mantienen en movimiento) al corazón y no al revés. Esto significa que las tripas, aunque son cosas "de menor aprecio", son tan necesarias como el corazón. Las tripas representan lo más bajo del cuerpo, la digestión y la excreción. Se cita un ejemplo del Quijote:

> CERV. Quix. tom. 2. cap. 47. Menester será estár bien mantenidos,
>   porque tripas llevan corazón, que no corazón tripas.

El significado de este refrán es diferente pero la relación entre tripas y corazón ya está clara. Si el corazón necesita de las tripas, pero no al contrario, entonces el corazón puede faltarnos, mientras se puedan usar las tripas para sustituirlo (*hacer de tripas corazón*).

Answer (score 4):

La expresión efectivamente denota la acción de hacer algo pese a que resulte desagradable, contra la voluntad de uno. Esto lo explica el DRAE:

> [**hacer alguien de tripas corazón**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ah3RGfO)
>   1. loc. verb. coloq. Esforzarse para disimular el miedo, dominarse, sobreponerse en las adversidades.

Observo en el CORDE que su primer uso se remonta a 1773, en el texto *El cortejo escarmentado* de Ramón de la Cruz:

> Don Atanasio Ya es preciso hacer de tripas (Suelta el sombrero.)
>   corazón, porque estos trastos
>   vean que yo aquí supongo
>   más de lo que ellos dudaron.

El significado y explicación lo he visto discutido en el [Foro de Centro Virtual Cervantes (CVC)](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vcodigo=43640):

> La única explicación seudofisiológica que conozco es la que insinúa Francisco de Paula Seijas Lozano y Patiño cuando comenta el *Cuento de Cuentos* de Quevedo:
>
> > *Hacer de tripas corazón* significa esforzarse en disimular el miedo o el sentimiento, y es frase figurativa e ingeniosa. *Al que le falta corazón para estar tranquilo, hágalo de las tripas*, que ascienden a la cavidad del pecho cuando se retienen los suspiros.

Esta referencia a Quevedo tira la expresión más allá de lo dicho sobre el CORDE, pues Quevedo es del siglo XVII.

Sea como fuere, seguimos con información extraída del CVC:

> Las tripas son vísceras, lo mas hondo que se puede tener, al menos en sentido figurado, y así, cuando te falta el corazón para el perdón o los sentimientos al ver algo te impiden actuar, has de enviar la sensación que recibes al aparato digestivo, amén que te salga una úlcera o te produzca cáncer, y asumir lo que en realidad está pasando.

Por tanto, cuando *haces tripas corazón* lo que estás haciendo, metafóricamente, es convertir en razón o convicción (es decir, *corazón*) lo que las *tripas* te están diciendo.